# Do we need similar @RequestMapping value for both http get and post when we are going to use Spring @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

This is the question which is pressing my head since long time a go.

Suppose I have an index page and there's login form in there.

What I noticed is that for handling `@ModelAttribute` I should have instantiate the object of my model first in coming Http-GET request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderHomePage(@ModelAttribute("userCredential") UserCredential userCredential, ....){
     return "index-page";
}
```

and then I can fetch my Object when I post the form using HTTP-POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkCredential(@ModelAttribute("userCredential") UserCredential userCredential, ....){
     //do some user credential checking 
     return "faileOrSuccessPage";
}
```

and both method must have the same `@RequestMapping` value for the submission form to work.

now I have several question:

1. suppose my index page`(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)` has 10000 hit a day, Does it mean that for each coming get request, An object of UserCredential will be created? (I want to know about object life cycle)
2. Is there any methodology for us to bind a `@ModelAttribute` object with the second method (checkCredential) only (just when we want to submit a form)?
3. If in my case I just have to use `@RequestParam` to fetch my input values, how I can validate the `@RequestParam` without using `BindingResult` and return them back to the view for show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

.1. suppose my index page(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET) has 10000 hit a day, Does it mean that for each coming get request, An object of UserCredential will be created? (I want to know about object life cycle)

*Yes, but it is tied to the http request scope and the object will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as your page is rendered. 10000 is a fairly small number for the JVM to handle.*

.2. Is there any methodology for us to bind a @ModelAttribute object with the second method (checkCredential) only (just when we want to submit a form)?

*Depends on your flow - I am assuming you are using a spring form tag to show validation errors back to the user if the user or password don't conform to certain standards you have, if that is the case you will need to set the `@ModelAttribute` to populate your domain object at the point of redirection back to your index page. 
If on the other hand you don't intend to show feedback to your user with the original values that have been set by the user then you don't to set the ModelAttribute, you can totally ignore it and use normal `form` html elements instead of spring tag.*

.3. If in my case I just have to use @RequestParam to fetch my input values, how I can validate the @RequestParam without using BindingResult and return them back to the view for show?

*I wouldn't recommend this, a wrapper type is way better and will be validated with the registered validator and the `BindingResult` will cleanly have the validation errors that you can directly carry over to the UI. If you absolutely want to validate the `@RequestParam` on your own, you can call the validator yourself. There are ways to set more model attributes to carry back the validation exceptions and present on the UI.*

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, so you mean if I refresh my page, the object created for my previous @ModelAttribute will garbage collect ? what do you mean by wrapper type ? could you please address your answer to a sample or something ? thank you very much !!!

Comment: Yes, the previous object will be garbage collected and a new object will be created when you refresh your page

Comment: how about the wrapper type ?

Comment: By wrapper type I meant your `UserCredential` type rather than taking in username and password are `@RequestParam`

Comment: aha, what I'm looking for is a way to return the error back to UI without using the BindingResult because when we have BindingResult, we should have define @ModelAttribute before it and when It's not around an exception will throw away.
Do you know how to do that ? thanks man